# Has anyone managed to install an HP All-In-One printer on 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows-7, hp, 64-bit, printer

I'm trying to set up an HP All-In-One printer (6310) on a 64-bit Windows 7 system.  The setup for the driver software runs OK, but fails to connect to the printer across the network.  I haven't tried USB because this printer works over Ethernet with the other computers in the office and has worked on this PC too (before it was rebuilt).

I'm wondering if this is an x64 problem, or a Windows 7 problem... (it's been fine with Windows Server 2008 x64, Windows XP, Windows 7 32-bit) and was curious to see if anyone else had come up against similar issues with HP All-In-One devices on x64.

Comment: What parts are not working? If you just add it as a local printer against a new standard tcp/ip port and let it handle the driver - will it succeed and then work for printing? Can you ping and browse to it with a web browser from that computer? Sounds like there's a network problem?

Comment: It's the installation that fails to contact the printer across the network.  To be honest, I fail to see why HP has to supply so much software with the thing but I'm having to go through their installer in order to use the print and scan functionality.  I could try adding it manually as you suggest but then I won't have the scanner portion.

Comment: Are you using the software included on the install disk or downloaded from their website?

Answer (score 2):

I am now running Windows 7 x64 full time and had the same issue with an HP Officejet Pro L7590.

1. Verify you have the latest Windows 7 x64 compatible NIC drivers when connecting through Ethernet.
2. Verify you have the latest Windows 7 x64 compatible mother/mainboard drivers.
3. Download the latest driver install kit from HP. Since they don't have Windows 7 drivers officially released yet, use the latest Vista x64 available.
4. Run the HP driver/software installer in compatibility mode by right clicking, selecting properties, and then configure the Compatibility tab for Windows Vista SP1 or SP2.

The connection problem appears to have been the drivers for me. But once the connection issue was corrected with new drivers, the software would not work correctly after install until I ran it in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try to share it on the server and connect all clients through it?

Comment: If its a driver issue that is causing the problem then it is likely to still occur if its shared on a server

Comment: but most probably it's the "all in one software" that installs with it

Comment: It is the "all in one" software that's the problem.  I don't need to install it on a server because it's in a home office and effectively includes it's own print server (i.e. it has a built in Ethernet port and responds over TCP/IP... from every other PC... but not this one).

I suspect it's a 64-bit issue with the HP All-In-One software, but would be interested to hear from someone else who has experienced issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

I got a HP 2015 working with XP 64bit.  Its a nightmare I assure you.
Make sure to download the newest drivers from HP's site directly.

Manually install the printer!  DO NOT USE THE AUTOMATED PROCESS!!!

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be the 64 bit fault, because my Officejet 6310 works on my Vista 64.

But i had some troubles until they released an updated:

[link text][1]

Comment: That's a really nice link ;-)

Comment: Mathieu - that link doesn't seem to be there.

Thanks for answering this; however the fact that something works on Vista x64 doesn't necessarily mean it will on 7 x64 (although 99% of the time it will).

(I had it working on Windows Server 2008 - which is equivalent to Vista).

I suspect the problem is the HP setup, rather than the software itself.